# What is the difference between creating different dimens files directly and creating different values files with different dimens files?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, resources, android-resources

What I want is to have different dimens.xml files for each different screen size device. I have searched for information and I have seen in all the posts I found that they follow second path but I have not found any post which follows first path as I thought that could work and it was a more logical path.

What path is better, first or second? Are they exactly equivalent and could I use both of them for the purpose I want?

> First path: Android --> Values folder --> Right Click --> New --> Values
> Resource File --> File name: dimens --> Choose screen size qualifier
> --> Choose the density I want (Small, Normal, X-Large) --> Click OK
>
> Second path: Project --> res --> Right Click --> Android Resource Directory
> --> Resource type: values -->  Choose screen size qualifier --> Choose the density I want (Small, Normal, X-Large) --> Click OK --> add a
> specific dimens.xml file to each directory created

Answer (score 0):

> **Third path** -> Project --> res --> Right Click --> Android Resource
> **File** --> Resource type: values --> Choose screen size qualifier --> Choose the density I want (Small, Normal, X-Large) --> Click OK --> **Created directory and file**

the paths are the same, the difference is the first path creates a file you named before and the second path creates only a folder. You can use it which you want.

for more information about device compatibility [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility)